# Problemas con el tamaño de imagen CSS

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño `RATING` con css, estoy tratando de hacerlo de esta manera, pero tengo problemas con el tamaño de la imagen:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.rate {
    float: left;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: url(http://image.prntscr.com/image/bcdc244fb17643b6bbd75e95aa996faa.png);
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
     content: url(http://image.prntscr.com/image/97645296892344039d1e21f91432c8f2.png); 
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>5 star rating with css and html</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Como pueden ver imagen de las primeras estrellas (no seleccionadas), tiene  problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo cambie

```
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before
```

por

```
.rate > label
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.rate {
    float: left;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
}

.rate > label {
    content: url(http://image.prntscr.com/image/bcdc244fb17643b6bbd75e95aa996faa.png);
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
     content: url(http://image.prntscr.com/image/97645296892344039d1e21f91432c8f2.png); 
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>5 star rating with css and html</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!